# converting a column to be empty

Tags: sql

I have a two tables in which where one table has a datecolumn and other do not have, i have to main a union to fetch entries from both table

so as of now i am successful, but the empty fields showing invalid date like 1900-01-01, i want it  should be dispayed as null, like a cast into varchar

i am trying it like this

```
SELECT [orderid],CAST('' as [cancelleddate] as CHAR(20)) as [cancelleddate] ,'' as [cancelledtime]
```

The above is throwing error eventually

and doing this way will it effect performance

Comment: why is the above throwing an error?  did you copy it right.  It looks like the `''` spot is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT orderid, cancelleddate, cancelledtime FROM TABLE1

UNION

SELECT orderid, null, null FROM TABLE2
```

Comment: can i use the decode to check, if the value is not empty, populate with he date else make it null

Comment: Why not just make the date column in DB nullable?

Comment: its already nullable, its datatype is date, why it is doing it is because as i told above, there are two tables, in one table it is not defined and i am using '' as cancelleddate to be a dummy so union should work..., but it is populating the default date of 1901-01-01, so if i can use decode that will better

Comment: What database are you using?  Your query is populating the date of 1901-01-01?

Comment: sql server database i am using